# How to build a tree from a plain data structure

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I've the following array with objects:

```
var arr= [{id: "1", state: "1", ndi: "1558.3045298", children: "null"},
          {id: "2", state: "1", ndi: "1684.0732025", children: "null"},
          {id: "3", state: "1", ndi: "1809.8418752", children: "null"},
          {id: "4", state: "2", ndi: "1915.1603572", children: "null"},
          {id: "5", state: "2", ndi: "2023.5463678", children: "null"}]
```

How do I get an object tree where `state` is the root object of children?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific, on what you are trying to do? I don't see any tree-like structures in your data, and I don't know what you mean by "keeping state as the root element"

Comment: @maze-le In my case, I see the case clearly

Comment: @nisa Welcome to SO. I've edited your question so other might be able to understand your issue in a better way. Am I correct with my edit? Is this what you're looking for (see my answer too)?

Comment: @nisa This time someone (me) has edited your question. Next time try to be more concise or ellaborate better your questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking to organize the whole array so items are children of some states. Run the following snippet to get a JSON-serialized result to check it (click show code snippet to see the code and run it!):

```js
var arr = [{
  id: "1",
  state: "1",
  ndi: "1558.3045298",
  children: "null"
}, {
  id: "2",
  state: "1",
  ndi: "1684.0732025",
  children: "null"
}, {
  id: "3",
  state: "1",
  ndi: "1809.8418752",
  children: "null"
}, {
  id: "4",
  state: "2",
  ndi: "1915.1603572",
  children: "null"
}, {
  id: "5",
  state: "2",
  ndi: "2023.5463678",
  children: "null"
}];

// This is going to hold states by id
var states = {};

// We iterate the array to get an organized by state children version
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  // If state by id object hasn't the id yet we create an state object
  // for current state id. There will be no duplicated states.
  if (!states.hasOwnProperty(item.state)) {
    states[item.state] = {
      id: item.state,
      children: []
    };
  }

  // We add the item to the state by id object
  states[item.state].children.push(item);


  // This re-defines the state property to point to the 
  // item's parent state
  item.state = states[item.state];

  // We drop this property from the item because it's
  // disturbing the new organized tree ;)
  delete item.children;
});

var alreadySerialized = [];

// The second argument is required to avoid cyclic object
// serialization.
// Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify
document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(states, function(key, val) {
  if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
    if (alreadySerialized.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
      return;
    }
    alreadySerialized.push(val);
  }
  return val;
});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here's a sample resulting data after the transformation:

```
{
   "1":{
      "id":"1",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "ndi":"1558.3045298"
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "ndi":"1684.0732025"
         },
         {
            "id":"3",
            "ndi":"1809.8418752"
         }
      ]
   },
   "2":{
      "id":"2",
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"4",
            "ndi":"1915.1603572"
         },
         {
            "id":"5",
            "ndi":"2023.5463678"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Need to build a tree from above data using recursion. Here is an example of what I want to do. [see this url](http://jsfiddle.net/sw_lasse/9wpHa/)

Comment: @nisa So does my answer answered your question at all? In my case I thought you didn't need more than one nesting level.

Comment: I need to represent this tree structure in a html page. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/sw_lasse/9wpHa/). I can't get the buildTree() function right. Plz help.

Comment: @nisa If you feel that there's something that you don't understand, you should ask another question with an specific issue about that function that doesn't work. BTW, StackOverflow rules consider "this code isn't working" as off-topic...